# What type of join do I need?

Tags: php, mysql

For a registration page where the user enters their contact information and their username and password. I have two tables, one for a username and password with a foreignkey called contactinfo and a table of contact information that i want to join with the users table? Should both foreign and primary key also be set to auto increment?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set both primary keys to be auto increment. Add foreign key from user table to contact info table and your done. Foreign keys are *never* auto increment, after all they are meant to *refer* to a value in another table.

Note that if you are using an ORM like Doctrine the relationships between `user` and `contactinformation` will be handled automatically for you. Otherwise, you should insert your contact information first, get its generated primary key (via `mysql_insert_id` for example), then perform your insert into the `user` table.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, this is exactly what I have already. However my confusion is coming from when i add the data to the database. I would insert in to the users table the username and password but then how do i link the row to add the name address email etc

Comment: when you say i would need to get the generated key - would is there a way of always ensuring i get the right key back out?

Comment: You need to call `mysql_insert_id` right after `mysql_query`, to ensure that you get the correct key.

Answer (score 1):

user's table should have:

- userid (primary, autoincrement)
- username
- password

the other table has:

- infoid  (primary, autoincrement)
- userid (this will link this row to the other table)
- and your data...

you should use a "left join"

> The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all rows from the left table (table_name1), even if there are no matches in the right table (table_name2). (w3schools)

so we have a users table as our "left table" and info as "right table". user may not have info set just yet, but he/she has an account. so we have an account ("left") but not necessarily info ("right") - the LEFT JOIN sounds like the join for the job

and your sql should roughly look like

```
SELECT "columns" FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.userid = table2.userid

//where "columns" are the columns you want to get
//from the tables in "table.column" notation like: user.username or info.mobile
```